# What do the values in a dissasembler mean?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, embedded-linux

I created some C code, compiled it, and loaded it in a dissasembler...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc`, and then loaded it into a hex editor. This is what I got:

```
 7F 45 4C 46:02 01 01 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 03 00 B7 00:01 00 00 00|40 06 00 00:00 00 00 00
 40 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|A0 1B 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:40 00 38 00|09 00 40 00:1C 00 1B 00
 06 00 00 00:04 00 00 00|40 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 40 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|40 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F8 01 00 00:00 00 00 00|F8 01 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:04 00 00 00
 38 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|38 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 38 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|1B 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 1B 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:05 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 8C 08 00 00:00 00 00 00|8C 08 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 01 00:00 00 00 00|01 00 00 00:06 00 00 00
 90 0D 00 00:00 00 00 00|90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|80 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 88 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 01 00:00 00 00 00
 02 00 00 00:06 00 00 00|A0 0D 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A0 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|A0 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 F0 01 00 00:00 00 00 00|F0 01 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|04 00 00 00:04 00 00 00
 54 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|54 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 54 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|44 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 44 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 50 E5 74 64:04 00 00 00|A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 3C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|3C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|51 E5 74 64:06 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|10 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 52 E5 74 64:04 00 00 00|90 0D 00 00:00 00 00 00
 90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 70 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|70 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|2F 6C 69 62:2F 6C 64 2D
 6C 69 6E 75:78 2D 61 61|72 63 68 36:34 2E 73 6F
 2E 31 00 00:04 00 00 00|14 00 00 00:03 00 00 00
 47 4E 55 00:0F 74 19 3B|14 39 6A 1C:93 6A 47 85
 68 20 39 38:D0 E0 14 60|04 00 00 00:10 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:47 4E 55 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 00 00
 07 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|01 00 00 00:01 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 0B 00|B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 16 00
 00 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 10 00 00 00:12 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|4F 00 00 00:20 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:22 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|6B 00 00 00:20 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 22 00 00 00:12 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|7A 00 00 00:20 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 28 00 00 00:12 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 5F 5F 63:78 61 5F 66
 69 6E 61 6C:69 7A 65 00|5F 5F 6C 69:62 63 5F 73
 74 61 72 74:5F 6D 61 69|6E 00 61 62:6F 72 74 00
 70 72 69 6E:74 66 00 6C|69 62 63 2E:73 6F 2E 36
 00 47 4C 49:42 43 5F 32|2E 31 37 00:47 4C 49 42
 43 5F 32 2E:33 34 00 5F|49 54 4D 5F:64 65 72 65
 67 69 73 74:65 72 54 4D|43 6C 6F 6E:65 54 61 62
 6C 65 00 5F:5F 67 6D 6F|6E 5F 73 74:61 72 74 5F
 5F 00 5F 49:54 4D 5F 72|65 67 69 73:74 65 72 54
 4D 43 6C 6F:6E 65 54 61|62 6C 65 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 02 00:01 00 03 00|01 00 03 00:01 00 03 00
 01 00 02 00:2F 00 00 00|10 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 97 91 96 06:00 00 03 00|39 00 00 00:10 00 00 00
 B4 91 96 06:00 00 02 00|44 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|03 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 50 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|98 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 03 04 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F0 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|03 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 54 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 03 04 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 D8 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|01 04 00 00:04 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|E0 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 01 04 00 00:05 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 E8 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|01 04 00 00:06 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|F8 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 01 04 00 00:08 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A8 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|02 04 00 00:03 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|B0 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 02 04 00 00:05 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 B8 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|02 04 00 00:06 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|C0 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 02 04 00 00:07 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 C8 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|02 04 00 00:09 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|1F 20 03 D5:FD 7B BF A9
 FD 03 00 91:2C 00 00 94|FD 7B C1 A8:C0 03 5F D6
 F0 7B BF A9:90 00 00 90|11 D2 47 F9:10 82 3E 91
 20 02 1F D6:1F 20 03 D5|1F 20 03 D5:1F 20 03 D5
 90 00 00 90:11 D6 47 F9|10 A2 3E 91:20 02 1F D6
 90 00 00 90:11 DA 47 F9|10 C2 3E 91:20 02 1F D6
 90 00 00 90:11 DE 47 F9|10 E2 3E 91:20 02 1F D6
 90 00 00 90:11 E2 47 F9|10 02 3F 91:20 02 1F D6
 90 00 00 90:11 E6 47 F9|10 22 3F 91:20 02 1F D6
 1F 20 03 D5:1D 00 80 D2|1E 00 80 D2:E5 03 00 AA
 E1 03 40 F9:E2 23 00 91|E6 03 00 91:80 00 00 90
 00 F8 47 F9:03 00 80 D2|04 00 80 D2:E1 FF FF 97
 EC FF FF 97:80 00 00 90|00 F4 47 F9:40 00 00 B4
 E4 FF FF 17:C0 03 5F D6|1F 20 03 D5:1F 20 03 D5
 80 00 00 B0:00 40 00 91|81 00 00 B0:21 40 00 91
 3F 00 00 EB:C0 00 00 54|81 00 00 90:21 EC 47 F9
 61 00 00 B4:F0 03 01 AA|00 02 1F D6:C0 03 5F D6
 80 00 00 B0:00 40 00 91|81 00 00 B0:21 40 00 91
 21 00 00 CB:22 FC 7F D3|41 0C 81 8B:21 FC 41 93
 C1 00 00 B4:82 00 00 90|42 FC 47 F9:62 00 00 B4
 F0 03 02 AA:00 02 1F D6|C0 03 5F D6:1F 20 03 D5
 FD 7B BE A9:FD 03 00 91|F3 0B 00 F9:93 00 00 B0
 60 42 40 39:40 01 00 35|80 00 00 90:00 F0 47 F9
 80 00 00 B4:80 00 00 B0|00 04 40 F9:B5 FF FF 97
 D8 FF FF 97:20 00 80 52|60 42 00 39:F3 0B 40 F9
 FD 7B C2 A8:C0 03 5F D6|1F 20 03 D5:1F 20 03 D5
 DC FF FF 17:FD 7B BF A9|FD 03 00 91:00 00 00 90
 00 40 1E 91:B3 FF FF 97|00 00 80 52:FD 7B C1 A8
 C0 03 5F D6:1F 20 03 D5|FD 7B BF A9:FD 03 00 91
 FD 7B C1 A8:C0 03 5F D6|01 00 02 00:00 00 00 00
 48 65 6C 6C:6F 2C 20 57|6F 72 6C 64:21 00 00 00
 01 1B 03 3B:3C 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:A0 FE FF FF
 54 00 00 00:F0 FE FF FF|68 00 00 00:20 FF FF FF
 7C 00 00 00:60 FF FF FF|90 00 00 00:B0 FF FF FF
 B4 00 00 00:B4 FF FF FF|C8 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 10 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|01 7A 52 00:04 78 1E 01
 1B 0C 1F 00:10 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:44 FE FF FF
 34 00 00 00:00 41 07 1E|10 00 00 00:2C 00 00 00
 80 FE FF FF:30 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:10 00 00 00
 40 00 00 00:9C FE FF FF|3C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 20 00 00 00:54 00 00 00|C8 FE FF FF:48 00 00 00
 00 41 0E 20:9D 04 9E 03|42 93 02 4E:DE DD D3 0E
 00 00 00 00:10 00 00 00|78 00 00 00:F4 FE FF FF
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|1C 00 00 00:8C 00 00 00
 E4 FE FF FF:20 00 00 00|00 41 0E 10:9D 02 9E 01
 46 DE DD 0E:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 50 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|2F 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 0C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 0D 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|74 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 19 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 1B 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 1A 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|98 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 1C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F5 FE FF 6F:00 00 00 00|98 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 05 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|A8 03 00 00:00 00 00 00
 06 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|B8 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 0A 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|94 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 0B 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 15 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|90 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|78 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 14 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|07 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 17 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|40 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 07 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|80 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|C0 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 09 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 1E 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 FB FF FF 6F:00 00 00 00|01 00 00 08:00 00 00 00
 FE FF FF 6F:00 00 00 00|50 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 FF FF FF 6F:00 00 00 00|01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F0 FF FF 6F:00 00 00 00|3C 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F9 FF FF 6F:00 00 00 00|04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A0 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 54 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 47 43 43 3A:20 28 55 62|75 6E 74 75:20 31 31 2E
 32 2E 30 2D:37 75 62 75|6E 74 75 32:29 20 31 31
 2E 32 2E 30:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 01 00|38 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 02 00
 54 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 03 00|78 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 04 00
 98 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 05 00|B8 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 06 00
 A8 03 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 07 00|3C 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 08 00
 50 04 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 09 00|80 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 0A 00
 40 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 0B 00|B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 0C 00
 D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 0D 00|40 06 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 0E 00
 74 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 0F 00|88 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 10 00
 A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 11 00|E0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 12 00
 90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 13 00|98 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 14 00
 A0 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 15 00|90 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 16 00
 00 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:03 00 17 00|10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:03 00 18 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 03 00
 78 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 0C 00 00 00:01 00 03 00|78 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 20 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 00 00 00:00 00 0D 00
 40 06 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 09 00 00 00:00 00 11 00|F4 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 0F 00
 88 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 19 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 00 00 00:00 00 0D 00
 74 06 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 20 00 00 00:02 00 0D 00|74 06 00 00:00 00 00 00
 14 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 00 00 00:00 00 0B 00
 B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 16 00 00 00:00 00 0E 00|74 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|2D 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 16 00 00 00:00 00 0B 00|C8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 00 00 00:00 00 0E 00
 80 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 34 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 00 00 00:00 00 0D 00
 90 06 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 3F 00 00 00:02 00 0D 00|90 06 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|41 00 00 00:02 00 0D 00
 C0 06 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 09 00 00 00:00 00 16 00|08 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|54 00 00 00:02 00 0D 00
 00 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 6A 00 00 00:01 00 17 00|10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 13 00
 98 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 76 00 00 00:01 00 13 00|98 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|9D 00 00 00:02 00 0D 00
 50 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 09 00 00 00:00 00 12 00|90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|A9 00 00 00:01 00 12 00
 90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 09 00 00 00:00 00 11 00|08 08 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 17 00
 10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 C8 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 0F 00
 90 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 16 00 00 00:00 00 0D 00|54 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 11 00
 68 08 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 34 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|09 00 00 00:00 00 11 00
 88 08 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 CF 00 00 00:01 00 11 00|88 08 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:04 00 F1 FF
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 DD 00 00 00:01 00 F1 FF|A0 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|E6 00 00 00:00 00 10 00
 A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F9 00 00 00:01 00 F1 FF|D0 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 00 00 00:00 00 0C 00
 D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 0F 01 00 00:12 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|2C 01 00 00:20 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 8B 01 00 00:20 00 16 00|00 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|48 01 00 00:10 00 17 00
 10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 56 01 00 00:22 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|7E 01 00 00:10 00 17 00
 18 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 70 01 00 00:10 00 16 00|10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|77 01 00 00:12 02 0E 00
 74 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 7D 01 00 00:10 00 17 00|18 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|89 01 00 00:10 00 16 00
 00 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 96 01 00 00:20 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|A5 01 00 00:11 02 16 00
 08 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 B2 01 00 00:12 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|C3 01 00 00:11 00 0F 00
 88 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 D2 01 00 00:10 00 17 00|18 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|8F 01 00 00:12 00 0D 00
 40 06 00 00:00 00 00 00|34 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 D7 01 00 00:10 00 17 00|18 10 01 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|DF 01 00 00:10 00 17 00
 10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 EB 01 00 00:12 00 0D 00|54 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 20 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|F0 01 00 00:11 02 16 00
 10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 FC 01 00 00:20 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|16 02 00 00:12 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 28 02 00 00:12 02 0B 00|B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 53 63 72:74 31 2E 6F
 00 24 64 00:5F 5F 61 62|69 5F 74 61:67 00 24 78
 00 63 72 74:69 2E 6F 00|63 61 6C 6C:5F 77 65 61
 6B 5F 66 6E:00 63 72 74|6E 2E 6F 00:63 72 74 73
 74 75 66 66:2E 63 00 64|65 72 65 67:69 73 74 65
 72 5F 74 6D:5F 63 6C 6F|6E 65 73 00:5F 5F 64 6F
 5F 67 6C 6F:62 61 6C 5F|64 74 6F 72:73 5F 61 75
 78 00 63 6F:6D 70 6C 65|74 65 64 2E:30 00 5F 5F
 64 6F 5F 67:6C 6F 62 61|6C 5F 64 74:6F 72 73 5F
 61 75 78 5F:66 69 6E 69|5F 61 72 72:61 79 5F 65
 6E 74 72 79:00 66 72 61|6D 65 5F 64:75 6D 6D 79
 00 5F 5F 66:72 61 6D 65|5F 64 75 6D:6D 79 5F 69
 6E 69 74 5F:61 72 72 61|79 5F 65 6E:74 72 79 00
 6D 61 69 6E:2E 63 00 5F|5F 46 52 41:4D 45 5F 45
 4E 44 5F 5F:00 5F 44 59|4E 41 4D 49:43 00 5F 5F
 47 4E 55 5F:45 48 5F 46|52 41 4D 45:5F 48 44 52
 00 5F 47 4C:4F 42 41 4C|5F 4F 46 46:53 45 54 5F
 54 41 42 4C:45 5F 00 5F|5F 6C 69 62:63 5F 73 74
 61 72 74 5F:6D 61 69 6E|40 47 4C 49:42 43 5F 32
 2E 33 34 00:5F 49 54 4D|5F 64 65 72:65 67 69 73
 74 65 72 54:4D 43 6C 6F|6E 65 54 61:62 6C 65 00
 5F 5F 62 73:73 5F 73 74|61 72 74 5F:5F 00 5F 5F
 63 78 61 5F:66 69 6E 61|6C 69 7A 65:40 47 4C 49
 42 43 5F 32:2E 31 37 00|5F 65 64 61:74 61 00 5F
 66 69 6E 69:00 5F 5F 62|73 73 5F 65:6E 64 5F 5F
 00 5F 5F 64:61 74 61 5F|73 74 61 72:74 00 5F 5F
 67 6D 6F 6E:5F 73 74 61|72 74 5F 5F:00 5F 5F 64
 73 6F 5F 68:61 6E 64 6C|65 00 61 62:6F 72 74 40
 47 4C 49 42:43 5F 32 2E|31 37 00 5F:49 4F 5F 73
 74 64 69 6E:5F 75 73 65|64 00 5F 65:6E 64 00 5F
 5F 65 6E 64:5F 5F 00 5F|5F 62 73 73:5F 73 74 61
 72 74 00 6D:61 69 6E 00|5F 5F 54 4D:43 5F 45 4E
 44 5F 5F 00:5F 49 54 4D|5F 72 65 67:69 73 74 65
 72 54 4D 43:6C 6F 6E 65|54 61 62 6C:65 00 70 72
 69 6E 74 66:40 47 4C 49|42 43 5F 32:2E 31 37 00
 5F 69 6E 69:74 00 00 2E|73 79 6D 74:61 62 00 2E
 73 74 72 74:61 62 00 2E|73 68 73 74:72 74 61 62
 00 2E 69 6E:74 65 72 70|00 2E 6E 6F:74 65 2E 67
 6E 75 2E 62:75 69 6C 64|2D 69 64 00:2E 6E 6F 74
 65 2E 41 42:49 2D 74 61|67 00 2E 67:6E 75 2E 68
 61 73 68 00:2E 64 79 6E|73 79 6D 00:2E 64 79 6E
 73 74 72 00:2E 67 6E 75|2E 76 65 72:73 69 6F 6E
 00 2E 67 6E:75 2E 76 65|72 73 69 6F:6E 5F 72 00
 2E 72 65 6C:61 2E 64 79|6E 00 2E 72:65 6C 61 2E
 70 6C 74 00:2E 69 6E 69|74 00 2E 74:65 78 74 00
 2E 66 69 6E:69 00 2E 72|6F 64 61 74:61 00 2E 65
 68 5F 66 72:61 6D 65 5F|68 64 72 00:2E 65 68 5F
 66 72 61 6D:65 00 2E 69|6E 69 74 5F:61 72 72 61
 79 00 2E 66:69 6E 69 5F|61 72 72 61:79 00 2E 64
 79 6E 61 6D:69 63 00 2E|67 6F 74 00:2E 64 61 74
 61 00 2E 62:73 73 00 2E|63 6F 6D 6D:65 6E 74 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 1B 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 38 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|38 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 1B 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 23 00 00 00:07 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 54 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|54 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 24 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 36 00 00 00:07 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 78 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|78 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 20 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 44 00 00 00:F6 FF FF 6F|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 98 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|98 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 1C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|05 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 4E 00 00 00:0B 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 B8 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|B8 02 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F0 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:03 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 56 00 00 00:03 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A8 03 00 00:00 00 00 00|A8 03 00 00:00 00 00 00
 94 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 5E 00 00 00:FF FF FF 6F|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 3C 04 00 00:00 00 00 00|3C 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 14 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|05 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 6B 00 00 00:FE FF FF 6F|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 50 04 00 00:00 00 00 00|50 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 30 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:01 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 7A 00 00 00:04 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 80 04 00 00:00 00 00 00|80 04 00 00:00 00 00 00
 C0 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|05 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 84 00 00 00:04 00 00 00|42 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 40 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|40 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 78 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|05 00 00 00:15 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 8E 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|B8 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 89 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00|D0 05 00 00:00 00 00 00
 70 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 10 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 94 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 40 06 00 00:00 00 00 00|40 06 00 00:00 00 00 00
 34 01 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 40 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 9A 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 74 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|74 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 14 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A0 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 88 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|88 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 16 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A8 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|A0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 3C 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 04 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 B6 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|02 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 E0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00|E0 07 00 00:00 00 00 00
 AC 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 C0 00 00 00:0E 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 90 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|90 0D 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 CC 00 00 00:0F 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 98 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|98 0D 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 D8 00 00 00:06 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 A0 0D 01 00:00 00 00 00|A0 0D 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F0 01 00 00:00 00 00 00|06 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|10 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 E1 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 90 0F 01 00:00 00 00 00|90 0F 00 00:00 00 00 00
 70 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 E6 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|00 10 00 00:00 00 00 00
 10 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 EC 00 00 00:08 00 00 00|03 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 10 10 01 00:00 00 00 00|10 10 00 00:00 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 F1 00 00 00:01 00 00 00|30 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|10 10 00 00:00 00 00 00
 25 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:02 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|38 10 00 00:00 00 00 00
 40 08 00 00:00 00 00 00|1A 00 00 00:41 00 00 00
 08 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|18 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 09 00 00 00:03 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|78 18 00 00:00 00 00 00
 2E 02 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 11 00 00 00:03 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|A6 1A 00 00:00 00 00 00
 FA 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
 01 00 00 00:00 00 00 00|00 00 00 00:00 00 00 00
```

Then I searched for a string value like `Hello, world!`, and I got these bytes:

```
48 65 6C 6C:6F 2C 20 57|6F 72 6C 64:21
```

I am trying to create a kernel in C that can run linux programs, so I wanted to know what the hexadecimal values in the second code snippet meant, and how I could identify them in my kernel so that they could be runned on my kernel.

Comment: They are all numbers, and they are meaningful *in context*. Some are data, some are markers, some are addresses, some are processor instruction codes, and so on.

Comment: @WeatherVane I understand that, but which ones are processor instruction codes, and how could I make my kernel parse them?

Comment: Bytes 2,3 and 4 are ASCII representation of `ELF` so you should refer to the documented [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (as with any type of structured file).

Comment: FYI this is not a disassembler

Comment: @user253751 hex editor i mean